# How can I apply a font family to a React component

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

i'm trying to apply the following font:`https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Code+Pro`

I have downloaded the font into my folder and it looks something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EglMb.png)

I essentially have something like this:

```
<Box sx={{paddingBottom: '4%'}}>
     <AppWindow id='AppWindow'/>
</Box>
```

I have tried doing `sx={{fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro'}}` but it did not work out, I'm guessing I did not import the local files properly.

I have then tried using the import solution:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap');

#AppWindow{font-family: 'Source Code Pro'};
```

But that did nothing, the only way I managed to get the font to work somehow is using

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

But the problem with the above is it changes the font everything.

Another approach I have tried is changing the theme inside of theme.js:

```
import "@fontsource/SourceCodePro/300.css"

temp:{
  fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro'
}
```

but again I'm pretty sure I did not import the local files correctly. any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively use `webfontloader`. Firstly download it:

```
yarn add webfontloader # Or, npm i webfontloader
```

and then import to your component that you want to use the font:

```
import WebFont from 'webfontloader';
```

and when the component mounts it will load the desired fonts so you can use `useEffect` hook. Write the name of the font you want to download there.

```
useEffect(() => {
  WebFont.load({
    google: {
      families: ['Your Font Name']
    }
  });
}, []);
```

After that, you can use either className and edit your CSS or inline styling to use the desired font.